# Is there a way to count values by presence per rows in R?

Tags: r, dataframe, apply, counting

I want a way to count values on a dataframe based on its presence by row

```
a = data.frame(c('a','b','c','d','f'), 
               c('a','b','a','b','d'))
colnames(a) = c('let', 'let2')
```

In this reproducible example, we have the letter "a" appearing in the first row and third row, totalizing two appearences. I've made this code to count the values based if the presence is TRUE, but I want it to atribute it automaticaly for all the variables present in the dataframe:

```
#for counting the variable a and atribunting the count to the b dataframe

b = data.frame(unique(unique(unlist(a))))
b$count = 0

for(i in 1:nrow(a)){
  if(TRUE %in% apply(a[i,], 2, function(x) x %in% 'a') == TRUE){
    b$count[1] = b$count[1] + 1
  }  
}

b$count[1]
[1] 2
```

The problem is that I have to make this manually for all variables and I want a way to make this automatically. Is there a way? The expected output is:

```
1                         a     2
2                         b     2
3                         c     1
4                         d     2
5                         f     1
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It can be done in `base R` by taking the `unique` values separately from the column, `unlist` to a `vector` and get the frequency count with `table`.  If needed convert the `table` object to a two column data.frame with `stack`

```
stack(table(unlist(lapply(a, unique))))[2:1]
```

-output

```
#  ind values
#1   a      2
#2   b      2
#3   c      1
#4   d      2
#5   f      1
```

---

If it is based on row, use `apply` with `MARGIN = 1`

```
table(unlist(apply(a, 1, unique)))
```

Or do a group by row to get the `unique` and count with `table`

```
table(unlist(tapply(unlist(a), list(row(a)), unique)))
```

Or a faster approach with `dapply` from `collapse`

```
library(collapse)
table(unlist(dapply(a, funique, MARGIN = 1)))
```

Comment: Thank you so much, but that solution uniques the value per column, not per row. Is there any possibility to count the values based on row?

Comment: @sciencenmagic updated the post.  Sorry, I was checking the expected and both of them give the same output

Answer (score 2):

Does this work:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
a %>% pivot_longer(cols = everything()) %>% distinct() %>% count(value)
# A tibble: 5 x 2
  value     n
  <chr> <int>
1 a         2
2 b         2
3 c         1
4 d         2
5 f         1
```

Data used:

```
a
  let let2
1   a    a
2   b    b
3   c    a
4   d    b
5   f    d
```